# How to setup Application Insights for on-premise Service Fabric?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-application-insights, service-fabric-on-premises

Is it possible to add application insights for web api that's hosted on the on-premise version of service fabric?

So far I have tried to add the application insights to my project and wondering where to send for monitoring. It was easy when app is also on cloud.

I believe there is no on-premise application insights service, so even if the web api is hosted on-premise over service fabric; one must use cloud version application insights service, is that correct? In that case can anyone let me know how to setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "on premise" application insights, but as long as your on premise service has access to send outbound data, you can *use* application insights on your site.  You won't be able to use some features, like webtests, because application insights wont be able to make calls *into* your site.

Setup is the same as always, create an application insights resource in azure, and either configure it in visual studio, or manually set the instrumentation key in your applicationinsights.config (or via code) in your app.

If you need to configure outbound firewall rules or anything to let AI send data, that information is all here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-ip-addresses

Answer (score 2):

App Insights is only hosted in Azure. If you're looking for an on-premise solution, you're best off looking at using something like the ELK stack (Elastic Search, Logstash and Kabana).

Nonetheless, even though your cluster is hosted on-premise, using Asure App Insights is still very much a valid scenario (assuming your IT organisation is fine with it).

Assuming you're fine with Application Insights, I strongly recommend you have a look at [App Insights Service Fabric](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-ServiceFabric). It works great for:

- Sending error and exception info
- Populating the application map with all your services and their dependencies (including database)
- Reporting on app performance metrics, as well as,
- Tracing service call dependencies end-to-end,
- Integrating with native as well as non-native SF applications

One thing however that the above won't solve is providing overall cluster health information - e.g. when/how often nodes go up/down, how much CPU/Memory and disk IO is consumed on individual nodes. For this you could try MS [EventFlow](https://github.com/Azure/diagnostics-eventflow) or a [custom windows service](https://github.com/Adebeer/Service-Fabric-AppInsights-Health-Monitor)